# Design for JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, design-patterns

I'm currently developing an application with JavaFX using FXML Windows. the scope of the application is the following:

Get User Inputs (e.g. credentials) -> use these credentials to retrieve information using Web Services API calls -> use the collected information to either create a file or visualize in a table.

Currently, I am using the Main class to launch each FXML Window, return the info to the Main class and pass it to the next FXML Window and so on (e.g. Main -> FXMLWindow_1 -> Main -> FXML_Window_2 -> Main -> ...).

My question: Is this correct from a design / workflow stanpoint? Or would it be better / same to launch each FXML Window sequentially from the previous one (e.g. Main -> FXMLWindow_1 -> FMXLWindow_2...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a "right way".

It all depends on what functionality the application provides. If the individual windows in it are logically connected and solve a common task, it is more appropriate to use the Main -> FXMLWindow_1 -> FMXLWindow_2 approach. Actually, these are the "wizard" tools. In them the navigation is prev, next and finish. Another example of such an architecture is the installers next -> next -> .... -> finish.

If the tasks are not connected and the user can choose whether and when to perform a task (to open a dialog, for example), it is best to use Main -> FXMLWindow_1 -> Main -> FXML_Window_2 -> Main... In this case, you may want to consider using a separate application storage object (MVC pattern at application level).

With both approaches, you can get an additional dialog that can be used to authorize the user before it is admitted to the actual portion of the application.

You alone need to decide which solution best suits your application.